# Percent Difference between elements from 2 matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

If i have a 22 by 25 table of values which depend on n and r, and a list of values that depends on r that is a 22 by 1 matrix, how can I find the percent difference between each element, by row in the matrix.

For instances, finding the percent difference for each element in the top row of the 22 by 25 matrix with respect to the first value from the 22 element vector.

here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ω = 50;
c = 299792458;
λ = 400;
t1 := (2*Pi*r)/(c + ω*r);
t2 := (2*Pi*r)/(c - ω *r);
t21 = t2/t1;
δtc = N[Table[t2 - t1, {r, 1, 22, 1}], 10];
invδtc = Reverse[N[Table[t2 - t1, {r, 1, 22, 1}], 10]];
A := (n r^2*Sin[(2*Pi)/n])/2;
δtp = N[Table[(4*ω*A)/c^2, {r, 1, 22}, {n, 3, 26}],10]; 
diff = N[Table[((δtc - δtp)/δtc)*100, {r, 1, 22}, {n, 3,26}], 10];
```

Here is my results, as u can see every row has the same answer, which obviously does not make sense:

[image]

Comment: Post the code you have, don't be shy

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You probably want to use `Set Delayed` (i..e, `:=`) instead of Set (`=`) when defining t1, t2, and A.

Comment: post code, note an image so folks can cut paste

Comment: just posted it at the end

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this toy example will help. Note in the following:

- `/` acts component-wis
- I have only shown fractional change, just multiply matrix by 100
- `MatrixForm` is just a display format. In the image of code it is being used for operations

  ```
  m1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 10}];
  m2 = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}];
  d = m1 - m2;
  p = d/m1;
  Grid[{{"m1", "m2", "m1-m2", "percent change"}, 
  MatrixForm /@ {m1, m2, d, p}}]
  ```

[image]

Comment: that definitely helps, but since my tables are not of the same dimensions, it does not seem to be working

Comment: @johng I apologize for missing different dimensions. As I read your question more carefully you may able to achieve result  using e.g.`Map[f,m,{2}]` where f subtracts is `#-e/#&`  (or 100 x), where e is the element and it isbeing applied at level 2. :)

Comment: No need for the apology, and i can try that, i have no idea what Map or the second recommended command is

Comment: @johng think of # as place holders. So `(#-e)/#&` (what I wrote was wrong) is just a more compact way of writing`Function[x,(x-e)/x]` or given  e, $f(x)=(x-e)/x$. Look at documentation re: levels. But as a start `Map[f,m,{2}]` where `m={{a,b},{c,d}} `yields `{{f[a],f[b]},{f[c],f[d]}}`. Good luck. Playing with small examples helps (me at least). :)

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrating with a 3 x 4 matrix.

```
table = {
   {1, 2, 4, 8},
   {1, 2, 4, 8},
   {1, 2, 4, 8}};
values = {2, 4, 6};

MapThread[N[100 (#1/#2 - 1)] &, {values, table}];

TableForm[%]
```

> ```
> 100.     0.       -50.    -75.
> 300.     100.     0.      -50.
> 500.     200.     50.     -25.
> ```

Checking last item, percentage difference between 8 and 6 is -25%.

Comment: :-D  You were more verbose when you answered him [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36031871/4712538).

Comment: Why not just ``100` (values/table - 1) // TableForm``?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 5}];
subtractRow = First@Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {1, 5}];
```

Maybe?

```
((arr [[#]] - subtractRow)/arr[[#]]) & /@ Range[First@Dimensions@arr] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: matrix form of result]

Or

```
Function[{arr, row}, ((arr [[#]] - row)/arr[[#]]) & /@ 
    Range[First@Dimensions@arr]][arr, subtractRow] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mathematica 12.0 and I was able to get the percent difference from two matrices simply through "normal" operations.  For example:

```
r1 = {{1, 3, 5, 4}, {5, 4, 5, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 5}}

rstarf2 = {{1.2482, 2.44921, 4.89503, 4.35648}, {4.89717, 4.1552, 4.61887, 
4.37045}, {4.24131, 2.48646, 1.02565, 1.19075}, {3.78053, 3.55694, 
4.49958, 4.18843}}

rstarf2 - r1 =
{{0.248201, -0.550792, -0.104967, 0.356484}, {-0.102826, 
0.155204, -0.381132, 0.370454}, {0.241307, -0.513542, 0.0256549, 
0.190748}, {-0.219468, 0.55694, 0.499581, -0.811568}}

diff2pct = (rstarf2 - r1)/r1 =
{{0.248201, -0.183597, -0.0209934, 0.0891209}, {-0.0205651, 
0.038801, -0.0762264, 0.0926134}, {0.0603266, -0.171181, 0.0256549, 
0.190748}, {-0.054867, 0.185647, 0.124895, -0.162314}}
```

Verified that the elements in the final matrix above are actually % differences.